Cause of slippery ice - pressure?
Why did people (Including Feynman) even belived that pressure is the reason that ice is slippery? I mean a very straightforward calculation shows that it is definitely not the case:

Instead of considering a mole of ice/water, let’s just consider one gram. Then the latent heat is 333 J, the volume of the 6 ice is $(917,000)^{-1} \,$m$^3= 1.091\cdot10^{-6}\,$m$^3$, and the volume of the water is $1.000\cdot10^{-6} \,$m$^3$. Therefore the slope of the phase boundary is


$$\frac{dP}{dT}=\frac L{T\Delta V}=\frac{333\mathrm J}{(273 \mathrm K)(0.091\cdot10^{-6} \,\mathrm m^3)}=-1.35\cdot10^7\,\mathrm{Pa}/\mathrm K=-135\, \mathrm{bar}/\mathrm{K}$$


So if the temperature decreases by one degree (from 0 to 1 C), the pressure must increase by 135 bars to remain on the phase boundary. In other words, ice will melt at 1 C if the pressure is above 135 bars (or 133 atmospheres).

(Problem 5.32 part b, An introduction to thermal physics by Daniel V. Schroeder)
Even the variables used in this equation are easily measurable (latent heat of conversation of ice to water, temperature of ice, change in volume of ice when it melts), so why did this easily disprovable assumption eluded so many people?

Because explaining slippery ice and other common phenomena is not something people do even back of the napkin calculations for. They recall some physical effect that seems superficially relevant (like "pressure lowers the melting point") and leave it at that. The idea that pressure creates a liquid layer which makes ice slippery first popped back in 1886 when Irish physicist John Joly proposed it, see Baird. It has been rejected since, but Google's AI still seems to serve it up.

Might be better fitted for Physics SE if the discussion is about what is the right physics description.

@gidds Thanks for adding this comment

You've not mentionend the circumstances. Is this a person wearing shoes, or skates? And if you have one gram of ice, it's not the whole gram that needs to melt. Only its surface. I remember being shown an experiment where a wire with a weight at each end is hung over a block of ice, and the wire slowly descends through the ice. Do you have an alternative explanation to melting under pressure?

... and in this case the ice re-freezes on the upper size of the wire.

(Much easier to read now!)
